# how to automate the insertion of SVG icons via vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

how to display an icon by **type** attr in vue.js?

**HTML**

```
<icon type="heart"></icon>
<icon type="heartFull"></icon>
```

**Vue**

```
Vue.component('icon', {
data: {
    type: {
        heart: '<g stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="#c3cad5" stroke="#c3cad5"><path fill="none" stroke="#c3cad5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M21.243,3.757 c-2.343-2.343-6.142-2.343-8.485,0c-0.289,0.289-0.54,0.6-0.757,0.927c-0.217-0.327-0.469-0.639-0.757-0.927 c-2.343-2.343-6.142-2.343-8.485,0c-2.343,2.343-2.343,6.142,0,8.485L12,21.485l9.243-9.243C23.586,9.899,23.586,6.1,21.243,3.757z"></path></g>',
        heartFull: '<g fill="#c3cad5"><path fill="#c3cad5" d="M21.95,3.051C20.627,1.729,18.87,1,17,1s-3.627,0.729-4.949,2.05C12.034,3.067,12.017,3.084,12,3.102 c-0.017-0.018-0.033-0.034-0.05-0.051C10.627,1.729,8.87,1,7,1S3.373,1.729,2.05,3.051S0,6.13,0,8s0.728,3.627,2.05,4.949l9.95,9.95 l9.95-9.95C23.272,11.627,24,9.87,24,8C24,6.131,23.272,4.373,21.95,3.051z"></path></g>'
    }
},
props: {
    width: {
        type: Number,
        default: 24
    },
    height: {
        type: Number,
        default: 24
    },
},
computed: {
        viewBox() {
            return '0 0 ' + this.width + ' ' + this.height
        }
    },
template: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" :viewBox="viewBox" :width="width" :height="height">{{ type }}</svg>',
})
```

**Expected result**

```
<icon type="heart"></icon>
```

**it turns into**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24" width="24" height="24"><g stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="#c3cad5" stroke="#c3cad5"><path fill="none" stroke="#c3cad5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M21.243,3.757 c-2.343-2.343-6.142-2.343-8.485,0c-0.289,0.289-0.54,0.6-0.757,0.927c-0.217-0.327-0.469-0.639-0.757-0.927 c-2.343-2.343-6.142-2.343-8.485,0c-2.343,2.343-2.343,6.142,0,8.485L12,21.485l9.243-9.243C23.586,9.899,23.586,6.1,21.243,3.757z"></path></g></svg>
```

**or**

```
<icon type="heartFull"></icon>
```

**it turns into**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24" width="24" height="24"><g fill="#c3cad5"><path fill="#c3cad5" d="M21.95,3.051C20.627,1.729,18.87,1,17,1s-3.627,0.729-4.949,2.05C12.034,3.067,12.017,3.084,12,3.102 c-0.017-0.018-0.033-0.034-0.05-0.051C10.627,1.729,8.87,1,7,1S3.373,1.729,2.05,3.051S0,6.13,0,8s0.728,3.627,2.05,4.949l9.95,9.95 l9.95-9.95C23.272,11.627,24,9.87,24,8C24,6.131,23.272,4.373,21.95,3.051z"></path></g></svg>
```

In this way I would create more icons over time and use them easily. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for showing the expected result - that is very helpful.  What is the actual result that you see when you run your code?

Comment: **This:** `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" type="heart"></svg>`

Comment: Well your `type` is not a `prop` but a `data` property. And it is an `object`. So right now you are inserting the whole object `type` from your `data` into `svg`.

Comment: And can you give me solution please? Im new in this vue.js :)

Comment: BTW you can just import an svg an pass it as computed value to the template.. Then you don't have to have the full svg in the component, but rather an image in your asset folder. Depending on the type property, you can select the correct icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your type is not a prop but a data property. And it is an object. So right now you are inserting the whole object type from your data into svg.

Try this:

```
Vue.component('icon', {
  props: {
    iconType: {
      type: String,
      default: "heart"
    },
    width: {
      type: Number,
      default: 24
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      default: 24
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      types: {
        heart:
          '<g stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="#c3cad5" stroke="#c3cad5"><path fill="none" stroke="#c3cad5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M21.243,3.757 c-2.343-2.343-6.142-2.343-8.485,0c-0.289,0.289-0.54,0.6-0.757,0.927c-0.217-0.327-0.469-0.639-0.757-0.927 c-2.343-2.343-6.142-2.343-8.485,0c-2.343,2.343-2.343,6.142,0,8.485L12,21.485l9.243-9.243C23.586,9.899,23.586,6.1,21.243,3.757z"></path></g>',
        heartFull:
          '<g fill="#c3cad5"><path fill="#c3cad5" d="M21.95,3.051C20.627,1.729,18.87,1,17,1s-3.627,0.729-4.949,2.05C12.034,3.067,12.017,3.084,12,3.102 c-0.017-0.018-0.033-0.034-0.05-0.051C10.627,1.729,8.87,1,7,1S3.373,1.729,2.05,3.051S0,6.13,0,8s0.728,3.627,2.05,4.949l9.95,9.95 l9.95-9.95C23.272,11.627,24,9.87,24,8C24,6.131,23.272,4.373,21.95,3.051z"></path></g>'
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    viewBox() {
      return "0 0 " + this.width + " " + this.height;
    }
  },
  template:
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" :viewBox="viewBox" :width="width" :height="height" v-html="this.types[this.iconType]"></svg>'
};
})

<icon iconType ="heart"></icon>
<icon iconType ="heartFull"></icon>
```

Comment: Error: types is not defined

Comment: try `this.types`

Comment: Try now, I changed data: to data() it needs to be a function.

Comment: It works but doesn't put it as HTML, but as pure text between **"here"**

Comment: Oh wait, it doesn't work. It only inserts it from the **heart**, but if I change **type="heartFull"**, it won't change. It still only has the default value

Comment: You needed to pass `iconType` as prop since I've changed the name of it.

Comment: Okay, there was a problem. I can only have an icon here once and only the default value is taken, no matter what I write there. In the end i still have `new Vue({el: 'icon',})`. Could it be a source of my problems?

Comment: I solved it, the problem was with iconType, the attribute had to be lowercase. Thanks very much for the help!